# Association with base classes - How to solve an abstract type `error`

Tags: c++, inheritance, reference, associations, virtual-functions

### How can I avoid the error of abstract type, within the circumstances described in the tittle?

---

**CONTEXT**

I'm developing a Battleship game, where there is a Game class, that will have two players associated within it. The payers could be `Human`, or `Computer` in different levels of difficulty. However, because computers and humans are players, that have the same methods, I came up with the idea to use inheritance. Looks great, but not in practice.

**This is big, but readable reproducible example**

[/*  The code creates four classes: Player, Human, Computer, Game.
Human and Computer implement their own play methods, and game will receive as a parameter two types of players. /*]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Player
{
std::string Name;
public:
    Player(std::string myname):Name(myname){};
    ~Player(){};

    virtual int play() = 0;
    std::string name()
    {
        return Name;
    };          
};



class Human: public Player
{
public:
    Human(std::string myname ):Player(myname){};
    ~Human(){};

    int play()
    {
        return 1;
    }

    std::string name()
    {
        return Player::name();
    }

};


class Computer: public Player
{
public:
    Computer(std::string myname = "computer"):Player(myname){};
    ~Computer(){};

    int play()
    {
        return 2;
    }

    std::string name()
    {
        return Player::name();
    }

};


class Game
{
public:
    Player p1;
    Player p2;

    Game(Player myp1, Player myp2):p1(myp1), p2(myp2){};
    ~Game(){};

    void newTurn()
    {
        std::cout << "P1 plays: " << p1.play()
                << "\nP2 plays: " << p2.play();
    }   
};


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    Computer TheComputer;
    Human TheHuman("Jack");

    Game TheGame(TheComputer,TheHuman);

    TheGame.newTurn();
    return 0;
}
```

---

**THE ERROR**
You can check on you own compiler. But, in case that you don't have any access to own right now, this is a sample. Sample because, the errors that are accused for `p1` are for `p2`, but I'll just import the ones from `p1`.

```
teste.cpp:64:14: error: cannot declare parameter ‘myp1’ to be of abstract type ‘Player’
  Game(Player myp1, Player myp2):p1(myp1), p2(myp2){};
              ^
teste.cpp:4:7: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘Player’:
 class Player
       ^
 teste.cpp:11:14: note:     virtual int Player::play()
  virtual int play() = 0;
              ^

teste.cpp:61:9: error: cannot declare field ‘Game::p1’ to be of abstract type ‘Player’
  Player p1;
         ^

teste.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, const char**)’:
teste.cpp:80:35: error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type ‘Player’
  Game TheGame(TheComputer,TheHuman);
                                   ^
```

---

**WHAT I'VE TRIED**

Replacing this attributes to be a reference seems to be the solution to the problem, as it will the the responsibility to instantiate an object. Because the error persists (a little bit smaller), I know it is not sufficient

```
Player &p1;   //<< if you copy and paste(line 63)
Player &p2;   //<< if you copy and paste (line 64)
```

Comment: Open your C++ book to the chapter that teaches you all about references and pointers, and the explains the difference between passing function parameters by value, and passing by reference.

Comment: The time this question took me to write was much bigger then if I have done what you said (as the book is beside me). So, what you suggest has been made by me. But, thank you for your concern

Comment: And while you do that, your `Player` class should have a virtual destructor.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik could you please tell me the other post you find as being equal as mine? I did not find that, sorry